# Reseting the position of three/xr controllers

Tags: javascript, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei, webxr, react-xr

i'm using react three-fiber and react three-xr to create a 3d VR scene. My problem is as follows:
After doing: import { Controllers, Hands } from '@react-three/xr' and initialising controllers in my  that exists within , the controllers don't appear after entering the VR mode using the button, unless i leave the boundary area and return - as if they need a position reset to appear. Is there a way to fix that? Would appreciate any exemplary code

I tried accessing the Controlles via useXR(), but maybe i am doing something wrong. Either way could not find a solution for this

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).